# VS Code showing (peek) multiple definitions when I wan to jump to definition

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since the latest version(Version 1.32.1) that I keep getting definition peeks when i do ALT + Click to jump to definition

[image: Peek]

I'm not sure if this is a vsCode or a react types problem. The image below shows what I'm seeing in the first definition of the list (right side)

[image: Index.d.ts]

I'd like to be able to jump to file with one click instead of Click, then see definitions, then click again

Comment: This is the bane of my existence. I don’t suppose you worked out a solution?

Answer (score 8):

Adding this line in `settings.json` fixed it for me:

```
"editor.gotoLocation.multipleDefinitions": "goto"
```